# java 参照ライブラリにjarファイルを追加したが外部ライブラリが使えず？エラーがでます

Tags: java, eclipse

commons-io-2.11.0のReversedLinesFileReaderクラスを使ってファイルを下向きから読み込んで特定の文字列を検索したいです。
eclipseを使っています。java初心者でして外部ライブラリの使い方が上手くわかっていません。commons-io-2.11.0をダウンロードするとフォルダに複数のjarファイルがあり、どれを参照させればいいかわからず、適当に参照させてしまいました。

以下コードです。

```
package test1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        putLine("C:\\Users\\iroiro.txt","a","b");
    }
    public static void putLine(String filename, String searchString1, String searchString2) {
        try {
            File file1 = new File(filename);
            ReversedLinesFileReader fr = new ReversedLinesFileReader(file1);
            
            String line;
            while ((line=fr.readLine()) != null) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(searchString1);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                
                Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(searchString2);
                Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(line);
            
                if(m.find() || m2.find()) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                else {}
            }
            fr.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

パッケージの構造とでているエラーは以下の画像の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく `commons-io-2.11.0.jar` が **Modulepath** の配下に追加されていると思うので、下図の通り **Classpath** 配下に追加し直してみてください。

(この設定画面へは、パッケージエクスプローラでプロジェクト `test1` を右クリック > Properties(日本語メニューだとプロパティ？) から行けます)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます！その通りでした。変更しましたら実行出来ました。とても助かりました！本当にありがとうございます！！